# Can the identity matrix be negative?

Tags: matrices

I got the following question:
Find, if possible, the inverse of the matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}3, -1\\2, -2\end{bmatrix} $

and I did the following:
$\begin{bmatrix}3, -1\\2, -2\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}-2, 1\\-2, 3\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix}-2, 1\\-2, 3\end{bmatrix}$

Test: $( A * A^{-1} = I)$
$\begin{bmatrix}3, -1\\2, -2\end{bmatrix} *\begin{bmatrix}-0.5,0.25\\-0.5, 0.75\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}-1, 0\\0, -1\end{bmatrix}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your matrix's determinant has the wrong sign: it should be $\;\color{red}-\frac14\;$

Comment: Oh wow! Maybe it's time to eat something... Thanks!

Comment: In the above comment the determinant was meant to be $\;\color{red}-4\;$ , of course...

Comment: @amWhy That's a typo. Thanks though. Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V is dangerous

Comment: @Pontus (hehehe) Yes, I know the danger!

Comment: Have you found your answer? If so, why not help others? could you please change to a Q&A style post? (Remove the answer from the question, and post an answer yourself - Read more on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186983/how-to-correctly-post-a-qa-style-question-i-e-self-answer-without-it-failing)) Help build another great stackexchange knowledge base :)

Comment: Well no one has actually answered the question, can the identity matrix be negative? I only got an answer to my specific question but not the actual topic of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the identity matrix cannot be negative.  If your check yields $AA^{-1} = -I$ then something must have gone wrong.

Answer (score -1):

La faute est dans le calcul du déterminant, on a : ad-bc=-4 et non 4

The error is in the calculation of the determinant. We have $ad-bc=-4$ and not $4$.